# Unified language for developing apps for Android, WinMobile, iOS

Tags: javascript, android, ios, windows-mobile

Tell me if there is a common language for developing applications for the platform Android, Windows Mobile, iOS?
I mean, that is iOS Objective-C/J, for Android - Java, C++, Windows Mobile - C++ etc.
I'd even like to write in JavaScript (like JSCocoa for iOS), but I can't find a translator for other platforms. Are there any common solution implementation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Support for the 3 is available right now:
 - [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/)
 - [MoSync](http://www.mosync.com/)
 - [Rhodes](http://rhomobile.com/)

Support for the 3 is not available now, but on the roadmap:
 - [WorkLight](http://www.worklight.com/)
 - [QuickConnectFamily](http://quickconnectfamily.org/)
 - [MobileReflex](http://mobilereflex.com/)
 - [iPFaces](http://www.ipfaces.org/)

[(source)](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Multiple_phone_web_based_application_framework)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at: 
http://phonegap.com/

It's based on web standards.

more possibilities you can get from this question:

[Is there a multiplatform framework for developing iPhone / Android applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30953/is-there-a-multiplatform-framework-for-developing-iphone-android-applications)

Answer (score 1):

`LiveCode` is your easiest path to cross-plaftorm development, not only **IOS** and **Android**, but also for the desktop. Yes. **Mac, Windows AND Unix** --including server-side http server.

It's all packaged in a the closest thing to English you'll ever find.  Find out more at [Runrev](http://runrev.com).

I don't work for the publisher or have any financial interest in `LiveCode`.

Answer (score 0):

There are  few cross platform tools for developing mobile apps for many device and operating systems.

[Phone Gap](http://www.phonegap.com/)

[MoSync](http://www.mosync.com/)

Comment: Tell me please if I'll use the Phone Gap out of web browser is possible?

Comment: Sorry but I can't answer. I didn't work with Phone Gap or MoSync. I simply googled answers for you.